# Last message on room popup hides switch room link

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

In the current version of chat, the last message feature on the room popup hides switch room link.  This is frustrating b/c I have to go out of the room to get to my other room, instead of simply switching.

[image: Image Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good point. I've moved the links to the top. We might also shorten the "last" message, although I'd really like to keep it.

Comment: Links to the top is good enough for me.